# PHP, Dropzone Laravel 5.1 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: php, ajax, apache, laravel

I really hope someone can help me with this issue as I've tried everything I know.

**The Issue:**
Dropzone doesn't upload any images above 3mb instead shows 422 (Unprocessable Entity), images bellow 3mb upload perfectly fine. I've tried everything possible as well as spent plenty of time searching Google, I am receiving the issue both on local machine (Mac OSX using MAMP pro) and on my linux server (ubuntu 14.0). I believe this may be either a laravel or dropzone issue that I cant seem to figure out.

The File I'm trying to upload is straight from a cannon cam, 8mb filenames date+time.JPG, Ive checking the files via saving them as different outputs .jpg, .jpeg, .png however it still fails, they do work if I save them for web and optimize bellow 3mb however I need to be able to upload at least 9mb.

**PHP Ini Settings:**
upload_max_filesize = 30M
post_max_size = 30M

**Form Settings:**
Standard laravel open form with crftoken (_token)

**DropZone Settings:**

```
Dropzone.options.templateDrop = {
  maxFilesize: 30,
  maxThumbnailFilesize:15,
  acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
  init: function () {
    this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        //Show loader whilst uploading 
        $('.jqueryLoader').show();
    });
    this.on("complete", function (file) {
    //when images are fully uploaded reset div and functions within
      if (this.getUploadingFiles().length == 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0) {
            $('#galleryImageHolder').load(document.URL +  '  #galleryImageHolder', function(){
                galleryFunctions();
                $('.jqueryLoader').hide();
            });
        }
    });
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.
Kind Regards,
Martyn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing any server-side validation in Laravel? For example, my Upload Request sets a maximum file size on an upload:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'file' => 'max:2048'
    ];

    return $rules;
}
```